# R ggplot boxplot issues

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was currently attempting to create a boxplot for my RShiny application. I have some movies from a .csv. These movies are of various genres, and I would like to display them in boxplots per genre, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
                                                      Name Rating       Year     Genre
1                                 The Shawshank Redemption    9.3     (1994)     crime
2                                            The Godfather    9.2     (1972)     crime
3                                          The Dark Knight    9.0     (2008)     crime
4                                   The Godfather: Part II    9.0     (1974)     crime
5                                             Pulp Fiction    8.9     (1994)     crime
6                                             12 Angry Men    8.9     (1957)     crime
7                                               Goodfellas    8.7     (1990)     crime
8                                           Cidade de Deus    8.7     (2002)     crime
9                                                 Drishyam    8.7     (2015)     crime
10                                The Silence of the Lambs    8.6     (1991)     crime
11                                                   Se7en    8.6     (1995)     crime
12                                      The Usual Suspects    8.6     (1995)     crime
13                                             L<U+00E9>on    8.6     (1994)     crime
14                                      American History X    8.6     (1998)     crime
15                                                  Eskiya    8.6     (1996)     crime
16                                            Vishwaroopam    8.6     (2013)     crime
17                                            The Departed    8.5     (2006)     crime
18                                          The Green Mile    8.5     (1999)     crime
19                                             A Wednesday    8.5     (2008)     crime
20                                              Hera Pheri    8.5     (2000)     crime
21                                          Reservoir Dogs    8.4     (1992)     crime
22                             Once Upon a Time in America    8.4     (1984)     crime
23                                      North by Northwest    8.4     (1959)     crime
24                                                       M    8.4     (1931)     crime
25                                        Double Indemnity    8.4     (1944)     crime
26                             Witness for the Prosecution    8.4     (1957)     crime
27                                                Scarface    8.3     (1983)     crime
28                                                  Snatch    8.3     (2000)     crime
29                                      A Clockwork Orange    8.3     (1971)     crime
30                                             Taxi Driver    8.3     (1976)     crime
31                                       L.A. Confidential    8.3     (1997)     crime
32                                   To Kill a Mockingbird    8.3     (1962)     crime
33                                               The Sting    8.3     (1973)     crime
34                                         Rash<U+00F4>mon    8.3     (1950)     crime
35                                      Gangs of Wasseypur    8.3     (2012)     crime
36                                                  Haider    8.3     (2014)     crime
37                                 The Wolf of Wall Street    8.2     (2013)     crime
38                                        The Big Lebowski    8.2     (1998)     crime
39                                                    Heat    8.2     (1995)     crime
40                     Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels    8.2     (1998)     crime
41                                                  Casino    8.2     (1995)     crime
42                                       On the Waterfront    8.2     (1954)     crime
43                                       Dial M for Murder    8.2     (1954)     crime
44                                Kind Hearts and Coronets    8.1     (1949)     crime
45                                             Zootropolis    8.1     (2016)     crime
46                                               Gone Girl    8.1     (2014)     crime
47                                               Spotlight    8.1 (I) (2015)     crime
48                                  No Country for Old Men    8.1     (2007)     crime
49                                               Prisoners    8.1     (2013)     crime
50                                The Grand Budapest Hotel    8.1     (2014)     crime
51                                          Hababam Sinifi    9.5     (1975)     drama
52                                The Shawshank Redemption    9.3     (1994)     drama
53                                           The Godfather    9.2     (1972)     drama
54                                         The Dark Knight    9.0     (2008)     drama
55                                  The Godfather: Part II    9.0     (1974)     drama
56                                            Pulp Fiction    8.9     (1994)     drama
57                                        Schindler's List    8.9     (1993)     drama
58           The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King    8.9     (2003)     drama
59                                            12 Angry Men    8.9     (1957)     drama
60                                            Forrest Gump    8.8     (1994)     drama
61                                              Fight Club    8.8     (1999)     drama
62       The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring    8.8     (2001)     drama
63                                              Goodfellas    8.7     (1990)     drama
64                         One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest    8.7     (1975)     drama
65                                          Cidade de Deus    8.7     (2002)     drama
66                                    Shichinin no samurai    8.7     (1954)     drama
67                   The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers    8.7     (2002)     drama
68                                                Drishyam    8.7     (2015)     drama
69                                          Babam ve Oglum    8.7     (2005)     drama
70                                            Interstellar    8.6     (2014)     drama
71                                The Silence of the Lambs    8.6     (1991)     drama
72                                     Saving Private Ryan    8.6     (1998)     drama
73                                                   Se7en    8.6     (1995)     drama
74                                      The Usual Suspects    8.6     (1995)     drama
75                                             L<U+00E9>on    8.6     (1994)     drama
76                                      American History X    8.6     (1998)     drama
77                                        The Intouchables    8.6     (2011)     drama
78                                  La vita <U+00E8> bella    8.6     (1997)     drama
79                                              Casablanca    8.6     (1942)     drama
80                                   It's a Wonderful Life    8.6     (1946)     drama
81                                            Modern Times    8.6     (1936)     drama
82                                             City Lights    8.6     (1931)     drama
83                                                  Eskiya    8.6     (1996)     drama
84                                            The Departed    8.5     (2006)     drama
85                                            The Prestige    8.5     (2006)     drama
86                                                Whiplash    8.5     (2014)     drama
87                                        Django Unchained    8.5     (2012)     drama
88                                         De leeuwekoning    8.5     (1994)     drama
89                                               Gladiator    8.5     (2000)     drama
90                                          The Green Mile    8.5     (1999)     drama
91                                          Apocalypse Now    8.5     (1979)     drama
92                                   Das Leben der Anderen    8.5     (2006)     drama
93                                             The Pianist    8.5     (2002)     drama
94                                          Hotaru no haka    8.5     (1988)     drama
95                                   Nuovo Cinema Paradiso    8.5     (1988)     drama
96                                            Sunset Blvd.    8.5     (1950)     drama
97                                             De dictator    8.5     (1940)     drama
98                                          Paths of Glory    8.5     (1957)     drama
99                                                  Sholay    8.5     (1975)     drama
100                                            A Wednesday    8.5     (2008)     drama
101                                    De reis van Chihiro    8.6     (2001) animation
102                                        De leeuwekoning    8.5     (1994) animation
103                                         Hotaru no haka    8.5     (1988) animation
104                                          Mononoke-hime    8.4     (1997) animation
105                                          WALL<U+00B7>E    8.4     (2008) animation
106                                             Inside Out    8.3 (I) (2015) animation
107                                              Toy Story    8.3     (1995) animation
108                                                     Up    8.3     (2009) animation
109                                            Toy Story 3    8.3     (2010) animation
110                                           Finding Nemo    8.2     (2003) animation
111                                   Hoe tem je een draak    8.2     (2010) animation
112                                   Hauru no ugoku shiro    8.2     (2004) animation
113                                       Tonari no Totoro    8.2     (1988) animation
114                                        Song of the Sea    8.2     (2014) animation
115                                           Mary and Max    8.2     (2009) animation
116                                            Zootropolis    8.1     (2016) animation
117                                         Monsters, Inc.    8.1     (2001) animation
118                                                  Akira    8.1     (1988) animation
119                               Kaze no tani no Naushika    8.1     (1984) animation
120                          Tenk<U+00FB> no shiro Rapyuta    8.1     (1986) animation
121                         The Nightmare Before Christmas    8.0     (1993) animation
122                                     Belle en het Beest    8.0     (1991) animation
123                                        The Incredibles    8.0     (2004) animation
124                                            Ratatouille    8.0     (2007) animation
125                                                Aladdin    8.0     (1992) animation
126                           K<U+00F4>kaku Kid<U+00F4>tai    8.0     (1995) animation
127                                         The Iron Giant    8.0     (1999) animation
128                                   Pink Floyd: The Wall    8.0     (1982) animation
129                                             Persepolis    8.0     (2007) animation
130                                       Mimi wo sumaseba    8.0     (1995) animation
131                                 Hoe Tem Je Een Draak 2    7.9     (2014) animation
132                                             Big Hero 6    7.9     (2014) animation
133                                                  Shrek    7.9     (2001) animation
134                                            Toy Story 2    7.9     (1999) animation
135                        Kiki's vliegende koeriersdienst    7.9     (1989) animation
136                                          Pafekuto buru    7.9     (1997) animation
137                             Toki o kakeru sh<U+00F4>jo    7.9     (2006) animation
138                           Batman: Mask of the Phantasm    7.9     (1993) animation
139              J<U+00FB>b<U+00EA> ninp<U+00FB>ch<U+00F4>    7.9     (1993) animation
140                        Cowboy Bebop: Tengoku no tobira    7.9     (2001) animation
141                                         The Lego Movie    7.8     (2014) animation
142                                               Rapunzel    7.8     (2010) animation
143                                      The Little Prince    7.8 (I) (2015) animation
144                                         Wreck-It Ralph    7.8     (2012) animation
145                                      Fantastic Mr. Fox    7.8     (2009) animation
146                                           Kaze tachinu    7.8     (2013) animation
147                     South Park: Bigger, Longer & Uncut    7.8     (1999) animation
148                                            Waking Life    7.8     (2001) animation
149                   By<U+00F4>soku 5 senchim<U+00EA>toru    7.8     (2007) animation
150                                               Fantasia    7.8     (1940) animation
151                                        The Dark Knight    9.0     (2008)    action
152          The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King    8.9     (2003)    action
153                                              Inception    8.8     (2010)    action
154      The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring    8.8     (2001)    action
155         Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back    8.8     (1980)    action
156                     Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope    8.7     (1977)    action
157                                             The Matrix    8.7     (1999)    action
158                                   Shichinin no samurai    8.7     (1954)    action
159                  The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers    8.7     (2002)    action
160                                    Saving Private Ryan    8.6     (1998)    action
161                                           Vishwaroopam    8.6     (2013)    action
162                                  The Dark Knight Rises    8.5     (2012)    action
163                                              Gladiator    8.5     (2000)    action
164          Indiana Jones and the Raiders of the Lost Ark    8.5     (1981)    action
165                             Terminator 2: Judgment Day    8.5     (1991)    action
166                                                 Sholay    8.5     (1975)    action
167                                        1 - Nenokkadine    8.5     (2014)    action
168                                                 Aliens    8.4     (1986)    action
169             Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi    8.4     (1983)    action
170                                     North by Northwest    8.4     (1959)    action
171                                                Airlift    8.4     (2016)    action
172                               Baahubali: The Beginning    8.4     (2015)    action
173                                                   Waar    8.4     (2013)    action
174                                          Batman Begins    8.3     (2005)    action
175                     Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade    8.3     (1989)    action
176                                                    Ran    8.3     (1985)    action
177                                  Y<U+00F4>jinb<U+00F4>    8.3     (1961)    action
178                                     Gangs of Wasseypur    8.3     (2012)    action
179                                     Bhaag Milkha Bhaag    8.3     (2013)    action
180                                                 Haider    8.3     (2014)    action
181             Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens    8.2     (2015)    action
182                                         V for Vendetta    8.2     (2005)    action
183                                                   Heat    8.2     (1995)    action
184                                               Die Hard    8.2     (1988)    action
185                                   Hoe tem je een draak    8.2     (2010)    action
186                                            The General    8.2     (1926)    action
187                                               Deadpool    8.1     (2016)    action
188 Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl    8.1     (2003)    action
189                                     Mad Max: Fury Road    8.1     (2015)    action
190                                Guardians of the Galaxy    8.1     (2014)    action
191                                           The Avengers    8.1     (2012)    action
192                                      Kill Bill: Vol. 1    8.1     (2003)    action
193                                         The Terminator    8.1     (1984)    action
194                                                   Rush    8.1 (I) (2013)    action
195                                   The Bourne Ultimatum    8.1     (2007)    action
196                                                Yip Man    8.1     (2008)    action
197                                                  Akira    8.1     (1988)    action
198                                         Tropa de Elite    8.1     (2007)    action
199       Tropa de Elite 2: O Inimigo Agora <U+00E9> Outro    8.1     (2010)    action
200                                                   Baby    8.1 (I) (2015)    action
```

The 'boxplots' currently look like this:
[image]

The code I used:

```
  output$boxplot <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(all_movies, aes(x = Genre, y = Rating)) +
      geom_boxplot()
    p
    })
```

How do I get proper boxplots for this dataset? All help is appreciated

**EDIT** `dput(all_movies)`

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(42L, 38L, 36L, 39L, 27L, 1L, 
13L, 6L, 9L, 43L, 31L, 45L, 19L, 4L, 10L, 48L, 37L, 41L, 3L, 
16L, 29L, 25L, 23L, 21L, 8L, 49L, 30L, 32L, 2L, 34L, 18L, 47L, 
44L, 28L, 11L, 14L, 46L, 35L, 15L, 20L, 5L, 24L, 7L, 17L, 50L, 
12L, 33L, 22L, 26L, 40L, 62L, 42L, 38L, 36L, 39L, 27L, 72L, 78L, 
1L, 60L, 59L, 77L, 13L, 69L, 6L, 73L, 79L, 9L, 52L, 64L, 43L, 
71L, 31L, 45L, 19L, 4L, 76L, 66L, 53L, 65L, 67L, 54L, 10L, 37L, 
81L, 82L, 58L, 57L, 61L, 41L, 51L, 55L, 80L, 63L, 68L, 75L, 56L, 
70L, 74L, 3L, 90L, 57L, 63L, 105L, 127L, 97L, 123L, 126L, 125L, 
93L, 96L, 94L, 122L, 113L, 103L, 50L, 106L, 83L, 100L, 115L, 
120L, 86L, 116L, 111L, 84L, 99L, 117L, 109L, 108L, 104L, 95L, 
87L, 112L, 124L, 102L, 107L, 121L, 85L, 98L, 89L, 118L, 110L, 
119L, 129L, 92L, 101L, 114L, 128L, 88L, 91L, 36L, 78L, 140L, 
77L, 149L, 148L, 157L, 73L, 79L, 71L, 48L, 155L, 61L, 142L, 152L, 
74L, 130L, 132L, 150L, 23L, 131L, 133L, 162L, 135L, 141L, 146L, 
163L, 11L, 136L, 14L, 151L, 161L, 15L, 138L, 96L, 156L, 137L, 
145L, 144L, 139L, 153L, 143L, 158L, 147L, 154L, 164L, 83L, 159L, 
160L, 134L), .Label = c("12 Angry Men", "A Clockwork Orange", 
"A Wednesday", "American History X", "Casino", "Cidade de Deus", 
"Dial M for Murder", "Double Indemnity", "Drishyam", "Eskiya", 
"Gangs of Wasseypur", "Gone Girl", "Goodfellas", "Haider", "Heat", 
"Hera Pheri", "Kind Hearts and Coronets", "L.A. Confidential", 
"L<U+00E9>on", "Lock, Stock and Two Smoking Barrels", "M", "No Country for Old Men", 
"North by Northwest", "On the Waterfront", "Once Upon a Time in America", 
"Prisoners", "Pulp Fiction", "Rash<U+00F4>mon", "Reservoir Dogs", 
"Scarface", "Se7en", "Snatch", "Spotlight", "Taxi Driver", "The Big Lebowski", 
"The Dark Knight", "The Departed", "The Godfather", "The Godfather: Part II", 
"The Grand Budapest Hotel", "The Green Mile", "The Shawshank Redemption", 
"The Silence of the Lambs", "The Sting", "The Usual Suspects", 
"The Wolf of Wall Street", "To Kill a Mockingbird", "Vishwaroopam", 
"Witness for the Prosecution", "Zootropolis", "Apocalypse Now", 
"Babam ve Oglum", "Casablanca", "City Lights", "Das Leben der Anderen", 
"De dictator", "De leeuwekoning", "Django Unchained", "Fight Club", 
"Forrest Gump", "Gladiator", "Hababam Sinifi", "Hotaru no haka", 
"Interstellar", "It's a Wonderful Life", "La vita <U+00E8> bella", 
"Modern Times", "Nuovo Cinema Paradiso", "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", 
"Paths of Glory", "Saving Private Ryan", "Schindler's List", 
"Shichinin no samurai", "Sholay", "Sunset Blvd.", "The Intouchables", 
"The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", 
"The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", "The Pianist", "The Prestige", 
"Whiplash", "Akira", "Aladdin", "Batman: Mask of the Phantasm", 
"Belle en het Beest", "Big Hero 6", "By<U+00F4>soku 5 senchim<U+00EA>toru", 
"Cowboy Bebop: Tengoku no tobira", "De reis van Chihiro", "Fantasia", 
"Fantastic Mr. Fox", "Finding Nemo", "Hauru no ugoku shiro", 
"Hoe Tem Je Een Draak 2", "Hoe tem je een draak", "Inside Out", 
"J<U+00FB>b<U+00EA> ninp<U+00FB>ch<U+00F4>", "K<U+00F4>kaku Kid<U+00F4>tai", 
"Kaze no tani no Naushika", "Kaze tachinu", "Kiki's vliegende koeriersdienst", 
"Mary and Max", "Mimi wo sumaseba", "Mononoke-hime", "Monsters, Inc.", 
"Pafekuto buru", "Persepolis", "Pink Floyd: The Wall", "Rapunzel", 
"Ratatouille", "Shrek", "Song of the Sea", "South Park: Bigger, Longer & Uncut", 
"Tenk<U+00FB> no shiro Rapyuta", "The Incredibles", "The Iron Giant", 
"The Lego Movie", "The Little Prince", "The Nightmare Before Christmas", 
"Toki o kakeru sh<U+00F4>jo", "Tonari no Totoro", "Toy Story", 
"Toy Story 2", "Toy Story 3", "Up", "WALL<U+00B7>E", "Waking Life", 
"Wreck-It Ralph", "1 - Nenokkadine", "Airlift", "Aliens", "Baahubali: The Beginning", 
"Baby", "Batman Begins", "Bhaag Milkha Bhaag", "Deadpool", "Die Hard", 
"Guardians of the Galaxy", "Inception", "Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade", 
"Indiana Jones and the Raiders of the Lost Ark", "Kill Bill: Vol. 1", 
"Mad Max: Fury Road", "Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl", 
"Ran", "Rush", "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", 
"Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi", "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens", 
"Terminator 2: Judgment Day", "The Avengers", "The Bourne Ultimatum", 
"The Dark Knight Rises", "The General", "The Matrix", "The Terminator", 
"Tropa de Elite", "Tropa de Elite 2: O Inimigo Agora <U+00E9> Outro", 
"V for Vendetta", "Waar", "Y<U+00F4>jinb<U+00F4>", "Yip Man"), class = "factor"), 
    Rating = structure(c(11L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 11L, 10L, 
    9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 9L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("8.1", "8.2", "8.3", 
    "8.4", "8.5", "8.6", "8.7", "8.9", "9.0", "9.2", "9.3", "8.8", 
    "9.5", "7.8", "7.9", "8.0"), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(19L, 
    10L, 29L, 12L, 19L, 6L, 16L, 26L, 33L, 17L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 
    23L, 21L, 31L, 27L, 24L, 29L, 25L, 18L, 15L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
    6L, 14L, 25L, 9L, 13L, 22L, 8L, 11L, 4L, 30L, 32L, 31L, 23L, 
    20L, 23L, 20L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 34L, 32L, 35L, 28L, 31L, 32L, 
    40L, 19L, 10L, 29L, 12L, 19L, 43L, 45L, 6L, 19L, 24L, 44L, 
    16L, 40L, 26L, 5L, 26L, 33L, 46L, 32L, 17L, 23L, 20L, 20L, 
    19L, 23L, 47L, 22L, 38L, 39L, 36L, 1L, 21L, 27L, 27L, 32L, 
    30L, 19L, 25L, 24L, 41L, 27L, 26L, 42L, 42L, 4L, 37L, 6L, 
    40L, 29L, 44L, 19L, 42L, 22L, 29L, 35L, 20L, 52L, 53L, 45L, 
    53L, 51L, 42L, 32L, 52L, 34L, 44L, 42L, 15L, 49L, 43L, 17L, 
    51L, 28L, 18L, 20L, 24L, 48L, 28L, 20L, 32L, 32L, 44L, 24L, 
    50L, 22L, 27L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 32L, 53L, 35L, 30L, 52L, 31L, 
    24L, 44L, 28L, 37L, 29L, 45L, 53L, 44L, 57L, 56L, 24L, 5L, 
    26L, 23L, 31L, 30L, 25L, 58L, 17L, 40L, 32L, 49L, 14L, 7L, 
    34L, 33L, 31L, 46L, 50L, 59L, 55L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 46L, 
    20L, 42L, 53L, 54L, 34L, 45L, 33L, 32L, 30L, 45L, 15L, 60L, 
    28L, 29L, 42L, 28L, 53L, 35L), .Label = c("(1931)", "(1944)", 
    "(1949)", "(1950)", "(1954)", "(1957)", "(1959)", "(1962)", 
    "(1971)", "(1972)", "(1973)", "(1974)", "(1976)", "(1983)", 
    "(1984)", "(1990)", "(1991)", "(1992)", "(1994)", "(1995)", 
    "(1996)", "(1997)", "(1998)", "(1999)", "(2000)", "(2002)", 
    "(2006)", "(2007)", "(2008)", "(2012)", "(2013)", "(2014)", 
    "(2015)", "(2016)", "(I) (2015)", "(1936)", "(1940)", "(1942)", 
    "(1946)", "(1975)", "(1979)", "(1988)", "(1993)", "(2001)", 
    "(2003)", "(2005)", "(2011)", "(1982)", "(1986)", "(1989)", 
    "(2004)", "(2009)", "(2010)", "(1926)", "(1961)", "(1977)", 
    "(1980)", "(1981)", "(1985)", "(I) (2013)"), class = "factor"), 
    Genre = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("crime", 
    "drama", "animation", "action"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Rating", "Year", "Genre"), row.names = c(NA, 200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try passing your aesthetics inside the call to geom_boxplot, e.g.: `ggplot(iris) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width))` or for you `p <- ggplot(all_movies) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = Genre, y = Rating))`

Comment: @Zach I tried this one, but it results in the same one as above unfortunately

Comment: Edit `dput(all_movies)` into your post so we can get a reproducible example.

Comment: @Zach allright, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting solution as an answer:

From your `dput` output we see that the `Rating` column is a factor, in order to pass it to ggplot like you want it to be it needs to be a numeric so we need to recode it as:

```
all_movies$Rating <- sapply(sapply(all_movies$Rating, as.character), as.numeric)
```

Then we can pass it to ggplot:

```
ggplot(all_movies) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = Genre, y = Rating))
```

Comment: This does indeed work. Have just started with R, so did not figure this out yet. Thanks @Zach!